# difference between escape sequence \a and \b

Tags: python, escaping

I tried the following statements in python idle:

```
print "This is a \a try"
print "This is a \b try"
```

Both give the same output:

[image]

I am confused what is the difference between the two in practical usage?

Comment: Not sure what you mean - if you refer to [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals) you'll see that one is an ASCII Bell, the other an ASCII Backspace... so apart from they're different - not sure what you mean by practical usage....

Comment: by practical usage I mean that though they are theoretically different but when is their usage important?

Comment: Not theoretically different - they are different :) Is your *actual* question - "Why would I ever want to use either of them?" eg: You see the use behind `\t` and `\n` etc... But what would you use `\a` or `\b` for... ?

Comment: The [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character set was introduced in the sixties. Do you expect that everything that was defined 50 years ago should make sense now? Computers, I/O devices and their usage were completely different then. I don't see how your question is relevant to python.

Answer (score 0):

These are actually different strings:

```
>>> "This is a \a try"
'This is a \x07 try'
>>> "This is a \b try"
'This is a \x08 try'
```

It turns out that symbols `\x07` and `\x08` are displayed the same way with your font when you print these strings.

Comment: so is that idle font??

Comment: Yes. In my IDLE they are printed as different symbols (phone and checkmark)

Answer (score 0):

`\a  0x07    Bell or alert

\b  0x08    Backspace`

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_strings.htm